# how can I define limit of an array by the quantity of numbers put in scanf?

Tags: c

Example: input: 420 50 -4
output: Numbers 3
Positive 2
Negative 1

and also for the same code:
input: 420 50 -4 7
output: Numbers 4
Positive 3
Negative 1

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 2 
int main()
{
  int a[N], i=0, n=0, k=0, z=0; 

  for(i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
     scanf("%d" , &a[i]);

     if((a[i] >= -10000 && a[i] <= 10000 ))
       n++;
     if(a[i]>0)
       k++;
     if(a[i]<0)
       z++;
  }

  printf("Numbers:%d \n", n);
  printf("Positive:%d \n", k);
  printf("Negative:%d \n", z);

  return 0;
}
```

new issue
So the idea is this, I need my programm(mostly done by yano here) to only be able to load numbers ranging for -10000 to 10000 including border numbers, if other numbers would be loaded, the program should print the correct numbers, and ignore the incorrect (more like remove from array and replacing the element with the rest, which is correct, whilst reducing the total number of elements in the array)
example
input 140 -154161 20 30
output 140, 20, 30
Error: Input is outside interval!"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 10

void
printArray (const int *myArray, size_t numsEntered)
{
  int i, c = 0, k = 0, z = 0, s=0, l=0, sum=0, max, min;
  float pk, pz, ps, pl, prumer;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numsEntered; i++) //does math
  {

      sum = sum + myArray[i];
      if (i)
     printf (", ");
      printf ("%i", myArray[i]);
  
      if ((myArray[i] >= -10000 && myArray[i] <= 10000))
    c++;
      if (myArray[i] > 0)
    k++;
      if (myArray[i] < 0)
    z++;
        
     if(myArray[i]%2==0) 
    s++;
     else 
    l++;
 

    max = myArray[0];
    min = myArray[0];


        if(myArray[i] > max)
        {
            max = myArray[i];
        }
        if(myArray[i] < min)
        {
            min = myArray[i];
        }
  
  }


  if ((myArray[i] >= -10000 && myArray[i] <= 10000)) //checks if arrays are in range
  {
  prumer=(float) sum/2;
  pk = (float) k / c;
  pz = (float) z / c;
  ps = (float) s / c;
  pl = (float) l / c; 
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("Pocet cisel: %d\n", c);
  printf ("Pocet kladnych: %d\n", k);
  printf ("Pocet zapornych: %d\n", z);
  printf ("Procento kladnych: %.2lf\n", pk);
  printf ("Procento zapronych: %.2lf\n", pz);
  printf("Pocet sudych: %d\n", s);
  printf("Pocet lichych: %d\n", l);
  printf ("Procento sudych: %.2lf\n", ps);
  printf ("Procento lichych: %.2lf\n", pl);
  printf("Prumer: %.2lf\n", prumer );
  printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
  printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
}
 if (myArray[0]<-10000 || myArray[0]>10000) //checks if first element is in wrong range               
 programm prints arror and returns 0
 {
 printf("\n");
 printf ("Error: Vstup je mimo interval!");
 }


 }
int
main ()
{
  int lastArray = 0, end = 0, b = 0, i=0;
  size_t arraySize = INITIAL_SIZE;
  size_t numsEnteredSoFar = 0;
    int *myArray = malloc (sizeof (*myArray) * arraySize);// initially make room for 10
  if (myArray == NULL)
    exit (-1);

  while (1)
    {
      int curEntry, size = sizeof (myArray) / sizeof (int);
      char ch;
      if (scanf ("%d", &curEntry) == 1)
    {
      b = curEntry;
      end = numsEnteredSoFar;
      ch = fgetc (stdin);
 

      myArray[numsEnteredSoFar++] = curEntry;


      if (numsEnteredSoFar == arraySize)
        {

          arraySize += INITIAL_SIZE;
          int *temp = realloc (myArray, arraySize * sizeof (*myArray));
          if (temp == NULL)
        {

          fprintf (stderr, "out of memory\n");
          exit (-1);
        }
          else
        {

          myArray = temp;
        }
    
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numsEnteredSoFar; i++)
    if((myArray[i]<-10000 || myArray[i]>10000)) //checks if input is in range if not exits        


    {
        if (i)                                  //my attempt for making this work
        printf (", ");        
        printf ("%i", myArray[i]);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Error: Vstup je mimo interval!");
        exit (-1);
    }

      if (ch == 10)
    {

      break;
    } 

    }

printArray (myArray, numsEnteredSoFar);
  free (myArray);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you run my code you just cant put 4 numbers in without changing the code. So how do I increase the amount of numbers without needing to change it everytime?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Input `420 50 -4 7` is indeed 4 numbers (in range of [-10000, 10000]), 3 positives, 1 negative. You should check the return value of `scanf` and get rid of the extra set of parenthesis around your first `if` statement, but what's the problem?

Comment: If you're asking how to change the amount of numbers input, that is dictated by `N`, whose definition you don't show here. If it's a constant or macro, you need to change it and recompile. If it's a variable, you can `scanf` it just like the other values. Make sure you do that _before_ `int a[N]`

Comment: #define N 2  <----

Comment: yea I am aware but doing this will make input more complex, ofcourse I can just ask printf("select size of array %d\ n" N); my point is I want the input only to be the x numbers someone decides to put in

Comment: Best to post code as text, rather than a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example allows the user to enter numbers "indefinitely" without the need for prompting how many to enter.  Of course, your computer only has so much RAM, so there is a limit, but not a practical limit.  Essentially, you need to choose an initial size, then allocate more space dynamically when that size is reached.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 10

void printArray(const int* myArray, size_t numsEntered)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<numsEntered; i++)
    {
        printf("myArray[%zu] = %d\n", i, myArray[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t arraySize = INITIAL_SIZE;
    size_t numsEnteredSoFar = 0;
    int* myArray = malloc(sizeof(*myArray) * arraySize);  // initially make room for 10
    if (myArray == NULL) exit(-1);  // whoops, malloc failed, handle this error how you want

    while(1)
    {
        int curEntry;
        printf("enter a number, or 'q' to quit: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &curEntry) == 1)
        {
            // store in the array, increment number of entries
            myArray[numsEnteredSoFar++] = curEntry;

            // here you can check for positives and negatives, or
            // wait to do that at the end. The point of this example
            // is to show how to dynamically increase memory allocation
            // during runtime.

            if (numsEnteredSoFar == arraySize)
            {
                puts("Array limit reached, reallocing");
                // we've reached our limit, need to allocate more memory to continue.
                // The expansion strategy is up to you, I'll just continue to add
                // INITIAL_SIZE
                arraySize += INITIAL_SIZE;
                int* temp = realloc(myArray, arraySize * sizeof(*myArray));
                if (temp == NULL)
                {
                    // uh oh, out of memory, handle this error as you want. I'll just
                    // print an error and bomb out
                    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // realloc succeeded, we can now safely assign temp to our main array
                    myArray = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // the user entered 'q' (or anything else that didn't match an int), we're done
            break;
        }
    }

    // print the array just to show it worked. Instead, here you can
    // loop through and do your comparisons for positive and negative,
    // or you can continue to track that after each entry as you've
    // shown in your code
    printArray(myArray, numsEnteredSoFar);

    free(myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1ezojoKce)

Comment: smart, good job, I started beating my desk out of my incopetence.... thank you for saving my mental health good sir

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this problem:

1. Declare an array that's large enough to accommodate the largest conceivable size of your data.
2. Include a size at the beginning of your data, and use that to malloc your array.
3. Use a data structure that doesn't depend on a fixed size, such as a linked list.

Comment: if I declare such array it will lock the loop in endless scanf, at least I figured as much after trying to make it work

Comment: linked list seems logical thx

Comment: I would, 4. Process the predicate on-line and only update the counts. End at EOF.

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 0):

Several parts to the answer.

1. Either declare a nice, big array, bigger than you'll ever need, *or*, prompt the user for the size, and then use that user-entered size to declare or allocate the array.  (This is a popular strategy, but it's a lousy user experience, since the user shouldn't need to know or say how many numbers they're going to enter.)
2. Check the return value of `scanf`.  If the return value isn't 1, this means that `scanf` failed, and didn't input a number.  You can take this as an indication that the user stopped entering numbers.
3. Have *two* variables: the size of the array, and the number of numbers actually entered.  You set the number of numbers actually entered by noticing when `scanf` failed.  Then, later, when you work with the date in the array, you don't do `for(i = 0; i < N; i++)`, you do `for(i = 0; i < number_of_numbers; i++)`.
4. If you don't want to ask the user to explicitly enter the number of numbers, and you don't want to pick a "big enough" size in advance (either because you don't want to waste memory, or because you want to make sure the user can enter a *lot* of inout, potentially more than any number you picked), it's possible to dynamically reallocate an array bigger and bigger as the user enters more and more data, but that's an advanced topic.

Comment: will try thx for the effort

Comment: If I declare an array that is large I have to put in the numbers to fill the size of an array exactly cant I somehow delete the vacant space when numbers arent put in? As I understand I declared the size of an array by defining N

Comment: @SajLencV02 You do not have to fill the array exactly.  And you do not have to worry about unused space.  You can have an array `int a[100]`, and you can have 5 values in it (with 95 unused), as long as you keep a separate variable `int n_used = 5` to keep track of how many to actually use.

Comment: @SajLencV02 Did your instructor tell you that you have to fill the array exactly?  That you're not allowed to have unused entries at the end?  If so, my apologies, totally different problem then.

Comment: @SajLencV02 No, for an array declared as `int a[100]`, if you later find you're only using, say, 5 entries, there is no way to "delete the vacant space".  But this isn't usually a problem.